# How to setup date and fuzzy title search on elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I am building an Rails 5 app with an Angular 7 frontent.
In this app I am using Searchkick (an Elasticsearch gem) and I have indexed a model called Event that got attributes title (string) and starts_at (datetime).

I want to be able to build a query in the search controller where I am able to do the following:

1. Search the title with a fuzzy search meaning it do not have to match 100% (which it now require).
2. Search with a date range matching starts_at for the indexed Events.

**This is my controller index method**

```
def index
        args = {}
        args[:eventable_id] = params[:id]
        args[:eventable_type] = params[:type]
        args[:title] = params[:title] if params[:title].present?
        if params[:starts_at].present?
            args[:starts_at] = {}
            args[:starts_at][:gte] = params[:starts_at].to_date.beginning_of_day
            args[:starts_at][:lte] = params[:ends_at].to_date.end_of_day
        end
        @events = Event.search where: args, page: params[:page], per_page: params[:per_page]
    end
```

**I have added this line to my Event model**

```
searchkick text_middle: [:title]
```

**This is the actual query that is run**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": [{
                "term": {
                    "eventable_id": "2"
                }
            }, {
                "term": {
                    "eventable_type": "Space"
                }
            }, {
                "term": {
                    "title": "nice event"
                }
            }, {
                "range": {
                    "starts_at": {
                        "from": "2020-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                        "include_lower": true,
                        "to": "2020-02-29T23:59:59.999Z",
                        "include_upper": true
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "timeout": "11s",
    "_source": false,
    "size": 10000
}
```

The date search does not work (but I get no errors) and the title search must match 100% (even the case).

Thankful for all help!

Comment: Rather than using fuzzy search I would recommend using an ngram. The problem with fuzzy search is that it treats your correctly matching term as equal to an incorrectly matching term by whatever offset you have set. So "abc" matches "abc" and "aac" equally given an offset of 1. For the range query, you need a `bool` query with a `should` or `must` clause and your actual range field query `{range: {year: {gte: params[:date], lte: params[:date], boost: 10}}}`. I am using a similar query clause with ES 7.3.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. How would I use this with the hash above to build the query?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using Fuzzy queries, I would recommend an ngram analyzer.

Here is an example of an ngram analyzer:

```
analyzer: {
    ngram_analyzer: {
        type: "custom",
        tokenizer: "standard",
        filter: ["lowercase", "ngram_filter"],
        char_filter: [
            "replace_dots"
        ]
    }
},
filter: {
    ngram_filter: {
        type: "ngram",
        min_gram: "3",
        max_gram: "20",
    }
}
```

You will also have to add this code to your settings index:

```
 max_ngram_diff: 17
```

Then on your mapping, make sure you create two fields. 1 mapping for your regular field such as `name` and then another mapping for your ngram field such as `name.ngram`.

In my query, I like to give my `name` field a boost of 10 and my `name.ngram` field a boost of 5 so that the exact matches will be rendered first. You will have to play with this though.

In regard to your range query, I am using `gte` and `lte`. Here is an example:

```
query:{
   bool: {
      must: {
          range: {date: {gte: params[:date], lte: params[:date], boost: 10}}
      }
   }
}
```

I hope this helps.